# How Do I Open a browser on Emulator using Robot Framework and Appium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, appium, robotframework

I am trying to configure Robot Framework to open Chrome Browser in an android emulator. I have this code to do that:

```
*** Settings ***
Suite Setup       Set Library Search Order    SeleniumLibrary
Test Setup        Open page
Test Teardown     Close Page
Library           SeleniumLibrary
Library           Collections
Library           requests
Library           AppiumLibrary

*** Test Cases ***
Test_case_sample
    Go To    https://www.google.com
    Sleep    10s

*** Keywords ***
Open Page
    ${desired_capabilities}=    Create Dictionary
    Set to Dictionary    ${desired_capabilities}    deviceName    Demo_6_Inch
    # Set to Dictionary    ${desired_capabilities}    build    test_run
    Set to Dictionary    ${desired_capabilities}    platformName    Android
    Set to Dictionary    ${desired_capabilities}    name    test_case_Sample
    Set to Dictionary    ${desired_capabilities}    platformVersion    8.0
    Set to Dictionary    ${desired_capabilities}    deviceOrientation    portrait
    Set to Dictionary    ${desired_capabilities}    browserName    Chrome
    Set to Dictionary    ${desired_capabilities}    appiumVersion    1.7.1
    Set to Dictionary    ${desired_capabilities}    deviceType    phone
    Create Webdriver    Remote    desired_capabilities=${desired_capabilities}

Close Page
    Close All Applications
```

When running the script, I get the following error :

> 11:10:39.547  INFO    Creating an instance of the Remote WebDriver.
>   11:10:40.548  INFO    Could not connect to port 4444 on host 127.0.0.1
>   11:10:40.548  INFO    Could not get IP address for host: 127.0.0.1
>   11:10:41.561  FAIL    URLError: urlopen error [Errno 10061] No connection
>   could be made because the target machine actively refused it

I than started an instance of selenium webdriver at localhost:4444 . But this time I got this error:

> WebDriverException: Message: Error forwarding the new session Empty
>   pool of VM for setup Capabilities {appiumVersion: 1.7.1, browserName:
>   Chrome, deviceName: Demo_6_Inch, deviceOrientation: portrait,
>   deviceType: phone, name: test_case_Sample, platformName: android,
>   platformVersion: 8.0} Stacktrace:
>       at org.openqa.grid.web.servlet.handler.RequestHandler.process (RequestHandler.java:117)
>       at org.openqa.grid.web.servlet.DriverServlet.process (DriverServlet.java:84)
>       at org.openqa.grid.web.servlet.DriverServlet.doPost (DriverServlet.java:68)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service (HttpServlet.java:707)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service (HttpServlet.java:790)
>       at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.servlet.ServletHolder.handle (ServletHolder.java:841)
>       at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle (ServletHandler.java:535)
>       at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle (ScopedHandler.java:188)
>       at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle (Sessio...
>       [ Message content over the limit has been removed. ]
>       at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope (ContextHandler.java:1155)
>       at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle (ScopedHandler.java:141)
>       at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle (HandlerWrapper.java:132)
>       at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.Server.handle (Server.java:561)
>       at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.HttpChannel.handle (HttpChannel.java:334)
>       at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.HttpConnection.onFillable (HttpConnection.java:251)
>       at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded
>   (AbstractConnection.java:279)
>       at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.io.FillInterest.fillable (FillInterest.java:104)
>       at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run (ChannelEndPoint.java:124)
>       at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob (QueuedThreadPool.java:679)
>       at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run (QueuedThreadPool.java:597)
>
> ### at java.lang.Thread.run (:-1)

How can I overcome this and run the emulator?

Thanks for your suggestion to solve this

Answer (score 3):

Finally found the simple solution :

```
*** Settings ***
Library           SeleniumLibrary
Library           Collections

*** Variables ***

*** Test Cases ***
AndroidConnection
    ${Options}    Create Dictionary    androidPackage    com.android.chrome
    ${caps}    Create Dictionary    chromeOptions    ${Options}
    Set to Dictionary    ${caps}    platformName    Android
    Set to Dictionary    ${caps}    platformVersion    8.0
    Set To Dictionary    ${caps}    deviceName    emulator-5554
    Set To Dictionary    ${caps}    browserName    Chrome
    Create Webdriver    Remote    command_executor=http://localhost:4723/wd/hub    desired_capabilities=${caps}
    go to    http://www.google.com
    Close Browser
```